# Run directly from the meter to house, no secondary panel?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I want to run directly from the meter to house, no secondary panel:

Would the following portion of [this answer here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/75478/47125) apply to my situation?

> To feed a 100 ampere secondary panel 200 ft. from the main panel, you'll want to use 1 AWG copper or 2/0 aluminum conductors. This is large enough to safely carry 100 amperes, and to maintain power quality over the distance.
>
> NOTES:
>
> You'll want to feed the panel using 4 conductors (hot, hot, neutral, ground).
> You'll have to isolate the grounded (neutral) conductors and bus bar in the secondary panel.
> You'll have to install an adequate grounding electrode system at the outbuilding, and bond the grounding conductor to it.

Comment: no idea ... you did not say how far is the meter from the house

Comment: It's a solid answer, but is it the same question?  Not necessarily.  Now if you have a meter-main combination, with overcurrent protection and the first means of disconnect at the meter, the panel at the house really is a subpanel, and it does apply

Comment: Would this info help?  The electric company just ran new service from the street about 150ft to the pole on our property and installed a new meter on the pole. Now we are running service from that meter 160ft underground to the house.

Answer (score 1):

Per the 2020 code (230.85), you are now REQUIRED to have a disconnect outside of the house at the meter.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.