# Subpanel run to secondary floor apartment from basement

Tags: electrical

What size wire would I need to run a 100 amp subpanel 28 feet away? I have 6/3 wire would  that do it?

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/29077/33) might be helpful.

Comment: 6 AWG copper is not large enough for 100 amperes.

Comment: This does seem like a duplicate question.  Nothing against you Mel, it was cool to ask, it's a peculiarity of SE's format.

Comment: You can feed a 100A panel with #6, you just cannot put that feeder on a 100A breaker. The panel size does NOT have to match the feeder/breaker size. What is this panel going to feed?

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer the question..

You'd need 4 (Hot, Hot, Neutral, Ground) #1 AWG wires.

- 1 AWG supplies up to 110 amps
- 6 AWG supplies up to 55 amps

If you use the 6 AWG, you could only feed the subpanel with a 50A breaker. Essentially making it a 50A subpanel. It's best to go ahead and get the most out of it if you can by using #1 wire.