# What is the minimum gauge wire required to carry 100 amp service from the meter to the panel?

Tags: electrical

What size wire is required to carry 100 amp service from the meter to the panel?

Comment: You seem to have a misspelling in your title. Please edit. Also add details about run length, etc.

Comment: And what country are you located in ?

Comment: Do different countries have safer or less safe ratings for how much current a particular gauge of wire can carry?

Comment: No @fred_dot_u, different countries have different codes.

Comment: The question was unrelated to codes. The question is what size wire to use. That is irrespective to regulations, unless the OP edits the question accordingly.

Comment: @fred_dot_u I don't think the question can be answered without knowing the country and its codes.   Wire will actually carry more than it's typically rated to carry.   Insulatation types and availability also vary by country.

Comment: @fred_dot_u, the question is 100% related to codes. In the US under the NEC the wire size is quite different for a 100A residential service compared to commercial or a branch circuit. This is based on codes.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered for a 60' distance on the [DIY Stack Exchange](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29057/what-wire-gauge-do-i-need-for-a-100-amp-subpanel-at-the-end-of-a-60-wire-run) and provides additional references for longer or shorter runs.

I suggest that the spelling error is the keyboard proximity of the letters C and V and a missing R, indicating that the OP wishes to carry 100 amp service.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Shrug, Diy has a stealth downvoter of late.  It may be because the linked queston doesn't appear *at first glance* to apply.  I see where it does.

Comment: The down vote may have been because this question should have been flagged as a dupe of the link in the answer instead of repeating the answer.