# Running 240v power to detached garage for electric vehicle

Tags: electrical, wiring, subpanel, conduit, 240v

We have a detached garage approx 95ft away from the main house and we are looking to run a 240v circuit there.

Currently we have Romex wire running straight into the ground. (This is how it was when we moved into the house. I have attached a picture below.) This feeds basic outlets and the garage door. We would like to run either straight to a circuit, or a small sub-panel to provide for the 110v (outlets and garage door, and 240v - EV)

My plan is the following:

- Trench down 18" and run 1" PVC 40 Conduit to the garage
- Insert a 70amp Breaker to feed the 60amp sub panel in the garage
- Run 6/3 gauge wire from main panel in the PVC to the sub-panel in the garage
- From the subpanel - just run the 12/2 wiring into the main circuit that is fitted up now (From the wiring that comes through the ground), Also run off the 50amp breaker from SP, the 6/3 wirirng to the Nema 14-50 outlet to plug in the EV.

The other option could be to avoid the subpanel and just run wiring to a an outlet.

- Run a 50amp breaker & 6/3 wire + new 12/2 wiring through the garage
- Connect the 6/3 to a 14-50 outlet and the 12/2 to the existing 110v setup.

Any tips, corrections or redirection would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: **cables** contain multiple **wires** wrapped in a sheath.  If you run conduit, you can run cable but only if you like to suffer. You are also allowed to run individual wires.   Now, a very important question: the "Romex" you dug up: are there any markings on it?  Is it NM, UF, what kind of cable exactly and what size?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What wire gauge do I need for a 100 Amp subpanel at the end of a 60' wire run?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29057/what-wire-gauge-do-i-need-for-a-100-amp-subpanel-at-the-end-of-a-60-wire-run)

Comment: Thanks - Not sure if it is NM or UF. Also - what do you mean by suffer? You recommend I run the cables individually? or in the sheath?

Comment: @andy you can't strip the sheath off and run individual wires, unless the individual wires have their own markings/ratings, which is rare.  However you can buy individual wires with markings and most is dual-rated dry/wet. In cable, NM is not wet rated, must use UF.  Here's what I mean by "suffer". Flat cable counts for area like round cable of the max dimension.  2 wires in conduit can't exceed 31% conduit fill, so my calcs show 6/3 and 12/2 UF will be 1.34sq.in.... /.31 = 4.332si needed.  2-1/2" is 3.976si, so 3" required.  That's the trouble with cable...

Comment: Thank you @Harper. That makes more sense now. Is this why I have seen some youtube videos of people running 2-2-2-2 wires for 240v?
Or would you recommend just running 6/3 wire in 1" PVC to a SP and then run out from there?

Comment: 6/3UF **cable** is 1.22" across, so I think you will have some trouble fitting it in 1" conduit.  Due to the size and fill requirements the minimum conduit size is 2".  That's why I'm looking at individual THWN-2 wires.

Comment: Thanks @Harper - After reading over a few times, you think a 6/3 UF-B cable would be an easier solution? I will have access to a trencher - and can do the 24" easy enough. In addition, I would use the conduit body and Conduit for the wires running right to the ground. Is there a way to DM me?

Comment: @Andy we're not a "pro consultancy" site.  I'm into conduit for ease of servicing and expansion and damage resistance in-ground.  Buried cable is definitely easier (and reduces theft risk). The conduit at entry isn't *conduit* but is only a cable protector, so the fill rules do not apply.  It need merely fit.  And UF cable can be run exactly like NM cable inside the house.   Above #6 it stops being UF and becomes URD, MH and a couple other names.  So price e.g. 4-4-4-6Al, 2-2-2-4Al or 1-1-1-3Al, copper is not "deluxe" just a waste of money in large feeder.

Comment: Thanks @Harper - I will look into it and do my research into the AL v Co wires. If in my situation if I wanted to run it direct burial for 100ft, Living in Seattle. What would you personally recommend and the site to purchase (HD, lowes, wiresandcablesyourway etc) for this project. 50amp Breaker > out of house > Direct burial wire > into garage > 14-50 outlet.

Comment: Check them, but HD/Lowes/Menards are stupid overpriced on all but the most popular commodity items.  I would focus on genuine electrical supply houses that are local.  Tell them you are price conscious and know what you're doing.  Some will quote you "list prices" but some will give you trade prices. I believe Platt operates in WA, and City Electric and Greybar are semi-nationwide, **but it'd be a shame to pass up a local family-owned electrical supply merely because they're not a brand name**. Electrical gear is too heavy and low-value to economically ship, so mail order is usually a lose.

Comment: Thanks Harper - You recommend AL or CO? just deciding on - Bare copper ground (#8 x 100ft), and either #6 Copper XHHW or #4 Aluminium (#4 x 3 x 100ft) since it is going to a 14-50 outlet off a 50amp breaker. If I can't source them, I may just grab some 6/3 UF-B. HD/Lowes were 97c/ft for #6 Copper, which adds up wayyyy to fast.

Answer (score 3):

First, using any sort of NM cable outside is *right out of the question*.  Cannot do it; it's not *wet-rated*.  If you want to direct-bury cable, use UF or other types; however you want to run in **conduit**.  Running cable in conduit *isn't even crazy*, for reasons let's leave to another Q/A. So *let's armwave* that you will be using individual wires.  Fortunately those are almost all dual-rated dry/wet (THHN/THWN-2, the W being Wet).

### Conduit

For this reason, it's important that the conduit is either a) continuous from the panel to the destination; or b) stops at a large junction box to make a splice from THWN-2 to cable.

When laying conduit, keep your bends to an *absolute minimum* between access points; use **conduit bodies** at corners to give easy access. You see a conduit body in your picture, but you can't use that one because service wires are in it.

If you are willing to trade "being able to trench with a garden trowel" for "murderous price per foot", consider Rigid or IMC conduit, which only needs 6" of cover over top of it (12" cover for vehicle pathways).  But figure like $4/foot for the stuff, and a trip or two to the hardware store to have pipe threaded.  Upside: it's a viable ground path, so one less wire.

For PVC conduit, you need ot use Schedule 80 and you must have 18" of cover over top of it, so trench to 20".

### Wires

I'm going to list the wires by price per 100ft, since your distance is about that.  I'm getting these prices from wiresandcablesyourway.com.  All or THWN-2 or XHHW.

```
 1 x #8 bare copper ground $37
 3 x #6 copper conductor   $57 x 3, 60A max  OR...
 3 x #4 aluminum conductor $26 x 3, 60A max  OR...
 3 x #2 aluminum conductor $35 x 3, 80A max  OR...
 3 x #1 aluminum conductor $52 x 3, 100A max.  
 2 x #10 copper conductor, $30 x 2, 20A
```

Aside from aluminum being less than half the price, one reason to use it is that puts your wire size larger than #6.  On #6 or smaller wires, you must use an actually-white wire for neutral, which can make buying wires more expensive.  #4 and up, you can mark it with tape.  Grab a 5-pack of red/white/green/blue/yellow electrical tape for $4.

The 20A/120V circuit is a real problem. Because of the distance, you need to upsize the wires to #10 or you'll have alarming voltage drop.  Now let's do the math on this.  The two conductors are $60.  You won't need it if you get a subpanel.  A perfectly respectable 16 space subpanel can be had for $70.  That's a no-brainer if you ask me.

- With #6 feeder, you can comfortably use 1" conduit.
- With #4 feeder you can only use 1" conduit if you omit the 20A circit, and it'll be a hard pull.
- With #1 feeder you can only use 1-1/4" conduit if you omit the 20A circuit, and it'll be a hard pull.

The ground wire, presumably #8 copper, can be shared between the feeder and the 20A circuit.

### The subpanel

Here we are huge proponents of huge subpanels.  When buying the panel, the cost of extra spaces is super cheap.  After you've fit it, and *regret* getting too small a panel, it's super hard and expensive.  Better to skip a pizza and get a bigger panel: 16 space, even 24 space.   You'll thank us later.

"Circuits" are not "spaces".  A panel that claims "16 circuits" means an 8-space panel using duplex/"double-stuff" breakers.  That's deceptive advertising because most circuits these days needs AFCI/GFCI breakers, and those are not available in double-stuff.

### Other stuff e.g.  Your diagram

The weird cable with male ends on both ends is probably a "suicide cord" for running a generator. Or should I say a "murder cord" because his plan was to plug one end into a generator and the other end into the garage feed, to backfeed the garage then backfeed the house. And *maybe* he turns off his main breaker first and doesn't kill a lineman.  *(Because when a 120V generator backfeeds a 120/240-9600V poletop transformer, the voltage on the backside of the transformer is, guess what! 9600 volts.  That's how transformers work.)*

Even worse, it sounds like rather than running a 120/240V /3 cable, he was using two separate cables to backfeed each leg separately.  What a hokey-dokey rig.  [This is what fools like that do](https://www.cnn.com/2016/08/11/us/california-valley-fire-faulty-hot-tub/index.html).  Just remove the plug ends at one end so nobody can plug it in.

On the remaining buried cables, you might dig 'em up for a closer look.  If they are NM, tear 'em out - they are ruined.  NM is not wet-rated. If they are UF, see how deep they're buried.  If it's <24" it's too shallow, tear it out.  Otherwise you can disconnect it, pull it through the building, slip a Sched. 80 PVC conduit over it and rebury it (at the bottom, an elbow of course), and then provide physical protection up to a proper Code building entrance.  And then put them back in service.  Free wire :)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you again for all the input. Finally completed the job this weekend.
Things I did in the end.
Replaced a double 30amp breaker that ran to the hut, now runs to the garage.
Ran UF-B 8/3 wire on a 40amp
This is becuase the charger only runs max 32amp, so it made sense.
We ran it through a conduit body, into the ground 18" all the way to the garage. We placed PVC 40 10" into the ground and into a conduit body.
No wiring was exposed.
We rand it to an outlet in the garage, and a 14-50 outlet that plugs into the car.
Very happy with the outcome.
My costs were the following
125ft Southwire 8/3 UF-B - $162
Trencher rental $61
14-50 outlet + faceplate - $11
Double gangway + spacer - $6
Clamps for panel/outlet - $5
PVC 40 1.25" - $5
Conduit body x 2 $8
40amp HOM breaker - $9
Total: $267.

Comment: Thanks for posting the results as an answer. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm looking to do something similar, but I'm confused by your final solution based on the other answers I've seen. My understanding is to use Schedule 80 PVC at 18". Also, UF-B wire is for direct burial, not conduit. THHN/THWN wire should be used in conduit. Am I misunderstanding something?